# Node-Red on Bluemix - how to access the Node server files?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I created a Node-Red flow on Bluemix, did some development and it was working ok for a few weeks. Suddenly the server won't start and logs "[Error: No cloudant service found]". The cloudant db credentials in VCAP look ok to me. How can I look at other files which are used by the Node server to setup and run? I don't see any way to access them in Bluemix or via cf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node-RED looks for a cloudant instance with the name `<your-app-name>.cloudantNoSQLDB` as that is what the boilerplate/quick-start deploy processes uses when deploying your instance.

One explanation for it not finding the bound cloundant instance is if you have renamed your app.

The specific code deployed is available: https://github.com/node-red/node-red-bluemix-starter

The expected name of the cloudant instance is generated here: https://github.com/node-red/node-red-bluemix-starter/blob/25f216a61fba182c4f8d2594124e2e4bbbebc3a6/bluemix-settings.js#L80

Comment: That was very helpful. I learned from the bluemix-settings.js you pointed to that I can use an environment variable NODE_RED_STORAGE_NAME to identify the db service, and that is working for me.